# What are the differences between XNA 3.1 and 4.0?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

I have been away from XNA for a couple months and want to get back into it.  I had a game I was currently working on, but it was done in XNA 3.1. What are the differences between the two, and is it worth updating?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would say its very beneficial to update your XNA to 4.0 (especially if you want to work on windows phone 7)

There are a few changes (not a ridiculous amount though) between 3.1 and 4.0. 
Here is an excellent site that I have had bookmarked that will help you out! (its a cheatsheet)
[XNA 3.1 to 4.0 CheatSheet](http://www.nelxon.com/blog/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet/)

Comment: The link is dead. Here's the copy stored by the Internet Archive: [XNA 3.1 to 4.0 Cheat Sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20110107091510/http://www.nelxon.com/blog/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet/)

Comment: FYI, the link is alive again.

Answer (score 8):

XNA 4 restructured a lot of the graphics section of XNA, it also added support for more built in effects (as opposed to just BasicEffect.) XNA 4 also dropped Zune support and now supports Windows Phone 7 development in its Reach mode. Shawn Hargreaves posted a lot of comparison posts on his blog last year, for example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310004334/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/12/reach-vs-hidef.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

XNA4 introduced [DynamicSoundEffectInstance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb200104(v=xnagamestudio.41)) which opens up **HUGE** doors for dynamic audio.

**EDIT:**

Also note that you only have until February 7th to submit XNA 3.1 games for XBLIG. See [this post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xna/xblig-4-0-submission-now-open-on-app-hub).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few breaking changes, as [Shawn Hargreaves outlines here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918035859/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/16/breaking-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx), as well as new features, et cetera. A discussion of "what's new" in XNA 4.0 can be found in [the XNA documentation on the MSDN site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb200104%28v=xnagamestudio.41%29). You'll have to evaluate the new features and changes in the context of your current game and see if its worth upgrading -- certainly I'd think you should do it for new games.